# Mainmatter creates blank page

Tags: koma-script, double-sided, blank-page

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's thesis and I'm a bit confused as to why \mainmatter creates a blank page between my List of Tables and my first Chapter "Introduction". I'm using a thesisclass as my documentclass and openany doesn't help. For the directories and the title page I used:

```
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

and after the \listoftables command I used:

```
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Whenever I comment \mainmatter and \pagenumbering{arabic} out, there is no blank page.

Thank you!

Edit: I got a LaTeX-Template from my university, which is quite complex so I'm not sure if the following contains everything important, but here is a small example. I have a thesisclass.cls document with:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesisclass}
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,openany]{scrbook}
```

My main tex-Document then contains:

```
\documentclass{thesisclass}

\includeonly{%
titlepage,
text/introduction,
text/declaration,
text/appendix
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} 
\listoftables  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} 

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{Introduction}
blablablablabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Most likely `\mainmatter` is issuing a `\cleardoublepage` but that's impossible to say without knowing exactly which document class you are using. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To be able to help you. we need to know what document class you're using -- different classes define this operation in different ways.  Ideally, you should provide a small compilable file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem, so that a potential helper can copy and paste to experiment.

Comment: @campa and barbare beeton, thank you for the welcome! I edited my post on top, which should include a good example of my document.

Comment: @Sayne You can see for yourself that you can use `\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}` and still have the blank page.  That will make it easier for others to test what's happening.

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\mainmatter` should not be needed, because `\mainmatter` should already change the numbering of pages to the numbering style of the main matter. Similar for `\pagenumbering{roman}` after `\frontmatter`, If these commands are part of the template, the template is not the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your custom class does not redefine `\mainmatter` & Co. and their definitions are the ones of `scrbook`, the issue is that `\mainmatter` checks for one- or two-sided print but ignores `openany`. You can trick it by setting the corresponding flag to false for the time being

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
foo

\makeatletter
\@twosidefalse
\mainmatter
\@twosidetrue
\makeatother
baz
\end{document}
```

### However, *I wouldn't do it*

Even with `openany`, in a two-sided print it is common that odd pages are on the right and even pages on the left. What you seem to require here disrupts this customary page numbering. I'd say it's bad style.

Side comment: `\frontmatter` does already `\pagenumbering{roman}`, and `\mainmatter` does already `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, so no need to write those again.

Comment: Yeah your trick did actually work, thanks! So you would just leave the blank page for my thesis? I'm not sure if it was even intended since it was in the template without me doing anything, but I have never seen a blank page after the directories. Can you explain what's bad about keeping the "code" to trick mainmatter, if I'm going to submit the thesis as a pdf? Or should I keep the blank page in the Tex but remove it in the PDF itself?

Comment: You should do whatever your university's template does, as much as you are able.  If it does something your university doesn't want, then go to the trouble to figure out a fix.  If you're planning to only submit a pdf, then you can try the option "oneside".  But I'd be surprised if your university didn't want a printed copy.

Comment: @Teepeemm my university changed the rules to only digital submissions after Covid started, so they don't want any prints for now. The template isn't officially from the University as far as I know, but from my Professor. And the template is already 10+ years old, so yeah I'm not sure if my professor even knew about the blank page. Does using the trick remove anything important formatting-wise though?

Comment: @Sayne The template definitely has issues. For example, adding the list of floats to the table of contents with `\addcontentsline` might go wrong if said lists are more than one page long. The `scrbook` has a dedicated option `listof=totoc` for that.

Comment: With this hack, the empty verso page is not printed, however, the odd numbered pages are still right pages and have to be printed corresponding. You can see this in the page margins. So, because the empty left pages should only be omitted with single-sided document, maybe option `twoside=false` would be the better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The KOMA-Script author's answer to this question can be found in: [How can empty left pages be prevented in scrbook?](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_AvoidInterleafPage/), section “Transition to new page numbering style”:

> When changing the style of page numbers in the course of using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, a blank Left page may also be inserted. This happens exactly when the front part ends on a right page, for example page iii. Since the main part always starts on page 1, an empty left page must then inevitably be inserted. This is because odd numbered pages are always a right page. If no blank left page were inserted, a double-sided printout would print a right page on a back page, i.e. a left page. From this point on, all margins would be wrong.
>
> Since this possibly resulting blank page is mandatory, it should not be switched off. Of course there are tricks for this, but I strongly advise against it. If you don't want this blank page, you really don't want a double-sided document and should set `twoside=false` at `\documentclass`.